# How to build a new matching node environment using just a package-lock.json (no package.json) in docker

Tags: docker, npm

I'm not writing a node module or publishing, just wanting to use https://github.com/dataverity/chromehtml2pdf which is just a wrapper around google chrome puppeteer.

I have a working docker container which produced the `package-lock.json` and now I want to build another using the same versions of all the node tree. I am using npm 6.9.0.

If I try to use `npm ci` it complains about not having a `package.json` file. I create one with just a name and version, and it tells me `0 packages added`.

I try using `npm install` and it replaces my `package-lock.json` with one just referring to my package.

Running `npm init --y` also seems to ignore the lock file despite some SO comments suggesting it should use the lock file to construct the tree.

How can I use the `package-lock.json` file to construct a matching node environment in docker?

UPDATE:
what a mess: see https://github.com/zkat/cipm/issues/61 and
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979
it would seem that this area is a minefield. I see references to a separate barely-documented tool called `cipm`, but this may have been partially absorbed into `npm ci` but this is woefully documented.

Tried installing and running with a bare `package.json` but got error which is presumably from cipm as it's not in the `package-lock.json` file: `Cannot find module 'validate-npm-package-name'`

Comment: Stepping back and checking what the problem is, why can’t you transfer the package.json as well as the package-lock.json? The package-lock.json file is an optional file with extra configuration. It is not a replacement for package.json, it is in addition.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.
I haven’t got a package.json because i’m not building a package, I just want to use one piece of software that happens to be in npm and I want to build a matching environment to where it is deployed. I saw the existence of this lock file tracking all the versions and thought I could somehow use it to build a matching environment, is that not possible? or is the only way to manually create a package.json from all the elements in the package-lock?